# PHP mail function sends to Gmail and Live but doesn't send to my own email

Tags: php, email

I've got this script for a contact form that was working well on the old server. We needed to move on a new server and now it only works if I send emails to Gmail or Live address. If I try to send emails to my own email assistenzatecnica@actainfo.it, it doesn't work.

```
    $from = trim($_POST['email']);
    $message = trim($_POST['message']);
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);

    /*Invia mail*/
    $body = '<html><body>';
    $body .= '<p><strong>Da:</strong> '.$username.' - '.$from.'</p>';
    $body .= '<p>'.$message.'</p>';
    $body .= '</body></html>';
    $headers = 'From: '.$from.'' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail("assistenzatecnica@actainfo.it", "ActaPrivacy - Richiesta Assistenza", $body, $headers);
```

The php.ini file is exactly the same as the one from the old server. Server is linux and I left the default values

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

I don't know what else I can do, what's weird is that it works if I send to Gmail, so why it doesn't work when I send to my own mail?

I can already move to PHPMailer, but I would also like to understand why this is not working properly if it was working before and the settings are the same.

Comment: Is there any thrown when you try to send to your own email? Is there an email portal you can check to see if the email is generated?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I can't check if the mail was ever created, also I'm not too sure where to check for mail error logs

Comment: @MatthewGaiser I found the logs and this is what it says: `Jan 31 10:29:33 ActaPrivacy sendmail[2704]: unable to qualify my own domain name (ActaPrivacy) -- using short name
Jan 31 10:29:33 ActaPrivacy sendmail[2704]: alias database /etc/mail/aliases rebuilt by root
Jan 31 10:29:33 ActaPrivacy sendmail[2704]: /etc/mail/aliases: 0 aliases, longest 0 bytes, 0 bytes total
Jan 31 10:29:33 ActaPrivacy sm-mta[2813]: My unqualified host name (ActaPrivacy) unknown; sleeping for retry
Jan 31 10:29:35 ActaPrivacy sm-msp-queue[2820]: My unqualified host name (ActaPrivacy) unknown; sleeping for retry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do move to PHPMailer. Default php mail functions do not support modern security features. You can see that emails you received in gmail have a red padlock icon. Some of the mailboxes will never receive an unsecure email.

Comment: That's probably what I will do, but it still bothers me that something that was working before doesn't work anymore for some reason.